# How do I redirect PloneFormGen to a page depending on the value in a select variable?

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x, ploneformgen

I am using PloneFormGen 1.7.12 in Plone 4.3.3.  I have a large selection field that contains about 20 names.  It is required.  If the user picks one of the names, it should send them to a Plone Page template that has instructions for them.  If it picks any other page, it should send the user an email with their form results and takes them to a thank you page.

I have tried doing this with a python script, but what I am doing doesn't work.  The code in the script is:

```
REDIRECT = context.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect
URL=context.REQUEST.URL1 + '/'
FORM=context.REQUEST.form
school_name = context.REQUEST.form['school_name']

member = context.portal_membership.getAuthenticatedMember()
roles=member.getRolesInContext(context)

if school_name <> "Other-School not Listed":
    return False
else:
    return REDIRECT(URL + 'not_listed')
```

I put python:here.school_redirect() in the Custom Form Action override, but the URL displays:

python:here.school_redirect()

and the page displays "The address wasn't understood"

school_redirect is the id of the python script
not_listed is the id of the Plone page template
school_name is the id of the select field

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Joe Bigler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Custom Form Action` is a simple StringField, no a TALES expression field.

This means you can add `./school_redirect` to the `Custom Form Action`, but then you got other issues like returning `False` will not work, you need to redirect anyway. You also bypasses all validators and success handlers.

So imho another approach may be better:

**1. Override the success handler**

`Custom Success Action` Field on FormFolder. You may add a single expression or a python script, which returns the right value.

Field description:

> Use this field in place of a thanks-page designation to determine final action after calling your action adapter (if you have one). You would usually use this for a custom success template or script. Leave empty if unneeded. Otherwise, specify as you would a CMFFormController action type and argument, complete with type of action to execute (e.g., "redirect_to" or "traverse_to") and a TALES expression. For example, "redirect_to:string:thanks-page" would redirect to 'thanks-page'.

*Your `./school_redirect` needs only small changes to fit for this solution. Do not redirect yourself, just return the right id (of a page template/view/etc.)*

**2. Do not trigger the mail adapter**

For this purpose the Mail-Adapter provides a field called `Execution Condition`.

> A TALES expression that will be evaluated to determine whether or not to execute this action. Leave empty if unneeded, and the action will be executed. Your expression should evaluate as a boolean; return True if you wish the action to execute. PLEASE NOTE: errors in the evaluation of this expression will cause an error on form display.

Add a script or expression, which evaluates if the email needs to be triggered or not.

*You may reuse the `./school_redirect` script to compose the expression: `python: here.school_redirect() != 'not_listed'`*

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I will test this out and reply back with the results.  I appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks Mathias,  I tested your solution and it worked.  I appreciate the detailed information.  I now have a better idea of how some of the fields in Overrides works.